# Ошибка при получении изображения с камеры Kotlin, вылетает приложение

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, камера, android-camera

Никак не могу запустить камеру, нигде не нашел ответа на данную проблему.

Сама ошибка:

```
2022-04-17 23:33:45.233 4652-4652/? E/libprocessgroup: Failed to write '4652' to /sys/fs/cgroup/uid_10225/pid_4652/cgroup.procs: Permission denied
2022-04-17 23:33:45.233 4652-4652/? E/Zygote: createProcessGroup(10225, 0) failed: Permission denied
2022-04-17 23:33:47.520 4652-4652/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 4652
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "androidx.camera.core.impl.Config androidx.camera.core.impl.UseCaseConfigFactory.getConfig(androidx.camera.core.impl.UseCaseConfigFactory$CaptureType, int)"
        at androidx.camera.core.Preview.getDefaultConfig(Preview.java:472)
        at androidx.camera.core.internal.CameraUseCaseAdapter.getConfigs(CameraUseCaseAdapter.java:483)
        at androidx.camera.core.internal.CameraUseCaseAdapter.addUseCases(CameraUseCaseAdapter.java:208)
        at androidx.camera.lifecycle.LifecycleCamera.bind(LifecycleCamera.java:206)
        at androidx.camera.lifecycle.LifecycleCameraRepository.bindToLifecycleCamera(LifecycleCameraRepository.java:278)
        at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(ProcessCameraProvider.java:532)
        at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(ProcessCameraProvider.java:360)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.startCamera$lambda-2(MainActivity.kt:76)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$1EpLcM5u7cid15NBPMsr6OOvSP0(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Вот код:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.lang.ClassCastException
import java.lang.Exception
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService
    //lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    companion object{
        private const val TAG = "Camera"
        private val PERMISSION = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        private const val PERMISSION_CODE =10
    }
    private fun permissonGrant() = PERMISSION.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if(permissonGrant()){
            startCamera()
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                PERMISSION,
                PERMISSION_CODE
            )
        }
        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_CODE){
            if (permissonGrant()){
                startCamera()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Не получилось получить разрешение", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }
    private fun startCamera(){
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(
            Runnable {
            val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(pv_camera.surfaceProvider)
                }

            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA
            try{
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this,
                    cameraSelector,
                    preview

                )
            }catch (e: Exception){
                Log.e(TAG, "Bind error", e)
            }
        },
        ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }
}
```

Вот Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Так же **build.gradle**:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'

}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //camera
    def camerax_version = "1.1.0-beta01"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.1.0-beta03"
}
```

и **activity_main**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pv_camera"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Все делал по данному уроку на youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCe4UZA3Qyo (на 33 минуте у него уже запускается камера)

Прошу Вас мне помочь, может где то ошибся может что то пропустил или может есть более простой и лучший способ вывести изображение с камеры на экран.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел проблему
А все дело в

```
    def camerax_version = "1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha24"
```

Где я указал вместо версии 1.0.0 последнюю 1.0.2 кажется.
Все же непонятно почему в новой версии не запускается.